# Elastic search returning wrong results

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running a query against elastic search but the results returned are wrong. The idea is that I can check against a range of fields with individual queries. But when I pass the following query, items which don't have the included lineup are returned.

```
query: {
  bool: {
    must: [
      {match:{"lineup.name":{query:"The 1975"}}}
    ]
  }
}
```

The objects are events which looks like.

```
{
  title: 'Glastonbury'
  country: 'UK',
  lineup: [
    {
      name: 'The 1975',
      genre: 'Indie',
      headliner: false
    }
  ]
},
{
  title: 'Reading'
  country: 'UK',
  lineup: [
    {
      name: 'The Strokes',
      genre: 'Indie',
      headliner: true
    }
  ]
}
```

In my case both of these events are returned.

The mapping can be seen here:
https://jsonblob.com/567e8f10e4b01190df45bb29

Comment: what is the mapping of `lineup` field?

Comment: "but the results returned are wrong" - can you be more specific?

Comment: I am not sure if `mapping` is complete because it looks weird, is `lineup` `nested`, `multi_filed`, `object`? could you go through this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html) and tell us what exactly lineup is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [match_phrase](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-phrase) query, `match` query is looking for either *The* or *1975* and it find *The* in *The strokes* and it gives you that result.

Try

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "lineup.name": {
              "query": "The 1975",
              "type": "phrase"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```